# OCaml complexity of List.assoc

Tags: ocaml, complexity-theory, lookup

In the List module of OCaml, how is : `val assoc : 'a -> ('a * 'b) list -> 'b` implemented and (therefore) what is the complexity of this operation ? Is there a hashtbl hidden behind the scenes ?

Comment: The search is linear. The type `('a * 'b) list` is explicit and shows no hash table. Would `assoc` benefit from building a hash table? (No) Association lists are immutable and useful to shadow previous values by sharing common tails. Suppose you want to temporarily bind a key to a value, you only need to put the new entry in front of an existing list. Hash tables are O(1) and Lists O(n), but for small n the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is available online here: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml#L180-L182

```
let rec assoc x = function
    [] -> raise Not_found
  | (a,b)::l -> if compare a x = 0 then b else assoc x l
```

As you can see it's implemented as a linear search over the list.